# how to group time series data into stationary & non-stationary?

Tags: time-series

i have time series data (download at:-->http://www.4shared.com/rar/ft3YCN2H/Time_series_data.html)

consider potential values as time series data points(4th column)

`file<-read.table(filename.txt,skip=1)`
`ts_data<-file$V4  #final time seris vetor`

please,**give R script**/functions to be used from any package,for follwing

1. to cluster these time seris into 2 groups--stationary & non-stationary(by programming & not by visually seeing ACF/PACF graphs)
2. how to find best model(AR/ARMA/ARIMA/SARIMA/GARCH,etc) to fit over these data for future forecasting ?,i don't want manually for each file,kindly suggest automated script
3. how to transform non-stationary models to get best fit model(i dont know how to get best P(autoregressive order),Q(moving average),D(differencing order))

Comment: Could you, please, invest some time in formatting your question? Poorly worded questions are unlikely to attract attention (anywhere) and collect good responses (here), although @Emre generously tried to decipher the above and pointed to alternative (Matlab) solution.

Comment: You are asking people to do an enormous amount of work for you. Please ask some specific question, but be prepared to do some work yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if R has a package but the Machine Learning Group of TU Berlin has written a [MATLAB toolbox](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/paulbuenau/ssa/toolbox/) for nonstationary time series decomposition called [Stationary Subspace Analysis](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume12/mueller11a/mueller11a.pdf). Other references are

- Satoshi Hara, Yoshinobu Kawahara, Takashi Washio, and Paul von Bunau. **Stationary subspace
  analysis as a generalized eigenvalue problem**. In *Proceedings of the 17th International Conference on Neural Information Processing: Theory and Algorithms - Volume Part I*, ICONIP’10, pages 422–429, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2010. Springer-Verlag.
- Motoaki Kawanabe, Wojciech Samek, Paul von Bunau, and Frank Meinecke. **An information geometrical view of stationary subspace analysis**. In *Artificial Neural Networks and Machine Learning ICANN 2011*, volume 6792 of Lecture Notes in Computer Science, pages 397–404. Springer Berlin / Heidelberg, 2011. URL http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-21738-8_51

Comment: i am using "itsmr" package-autofit() function & grouped into 2 states,Am i correct?

1-method--->
`> t<-read.table(file.choose(),skip=1)`
`> t<-t$V4 #final time series data vector`
`> autofit(t)`
`Error in arima(x, c(p, 0, q)) : non-stationary AR part from CSS`

another method---->

`j<-tryCatch(red_money<-autofit(ts(t)),error=function(e)e ) `
`if(inherits(j,"simpleError")){print("Non-stationary")}`

but it takes more time

Comment: Sorry, I don't use R. Furthermore, this is not the place to ask programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applying SSA is definitely an option.

This is the original reference:

http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.214101

And this paper explains how to get the most non-stationary directions:

http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TNNLS.2012.2185811